# NeoVim: disable gui cursor in insert mode

Tags: neovim

I am trying to disable the cursor (guicursor) while in insert mode in neovim to emulate a typewriter style environment.

To that effect I set guicursor (default is `vim.opt.guicursor="n-v-c-sm:block,i-ci-ve:ver25,r-cr-o:hor20"` ) to `i:ver0` and `i:nil`. The first I inferred from the wiki (neovim.io) while the latter was just a stab in the dark.

`i:ver0` returns "invalid percentage," and `i:nil` also outputs an error message. Neither works.

I asked at neovim's github and they suggested to send an event from the UI, namely

`["busy_start"] ["busy_stop"] Indicates to the UI that it must stop rendering the cursor. This event is misnamed and does not actually have anything to do with busyness.`

My issue is I am at a loss as to how to accomplish that. Tried setting the usual vim.opt but they don't seem to take.

Also, if you have any idea on how to trigger that event only when entering insert mode, it would be greatly greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For someone who would stumble on this in the future, here is the OP question on github with answer: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/discussions/24612